What is the expectation of $R^2$ for for iid $y, x_1, ... x_k \sim N(0,1)$
$Y, X_1, ...., X_k$ are all iid $N(0,1)$ with $n$ samples.
I can't make any progress on this problem... I don't even know an approximation but from simulation it seems to be $k/n$.

What is the expectation of $R^2$ for $ Y \sim \alpha + \beta X_1$?
What is the expectation of $R^2$ with $k$ independent variables?

For the case of one variable, I was trying to find the expectation of the correlation squared of $X_1,Y$ but I have no luck.
For the case of one variable, I was trying to find the expectation of the correlation squared of $X_1,Y$ but I have no luck.
I see this problem (Expected Value of R squared), but there doesn't seem to be a solution to the simpler gaussian case.

In the problem you linked, there is a "y" for every "x" but in your problem, you seem to only have one "y". Is this correct? And in the first part of the question, are $\alpha$ and $beta$ based only on $Y$ and $X_1$?

There is one y vector for each set of X vectors. Yes, im bullet 1. alpha and beta are determined by OLS.

So you have $X_1, Y_1, \ldots, X_k, Y_k$ right? then should the first question be $Y_1 \sim alpha + \beta X_1$?
Also, you have misunderstood my second question. When determining $\alpha$ and $\beta$, are you using the entire data set? I think you are saying yes, but then what does the what does $R^2$ for $Y_1 \sim \alpha + \beta X_1$ mean?

no: $\vec{y} = \alpha + \beta_1 \vec{x_1}$ for the simple case. $\vec{y} = \alpha + \beta_1 \vec{x_1} + ... + \beta_k \vec{x_k}$. where $y, \vec{x}i \sim MVN(0, 1){n \times 1}$

Ah that makes sense! So your first question is the same as the link you provided, except the distribution is different. Doesn't the answer there not care about the distribution?

I am asking for $k$ values though. This seems to simulate to be $k/n$
